# Concurrency Kit code builds fine in RHEL 7 but got compile errors in Linuxmint with same gcc version

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, concurrency, linux-mint

I got a project using Concurrency Kit. And I¡¯d like to build it in Linuxmint 17 using gcc 4.8.2, getting following errors. Oddly, I don¡¯t have these error when building in RHEL 7 (Redhat Enterprise Linux)/Centos 7 using gcc 4.8.2 too, exactly same code and makefile. So:

- Why? Does Redhat change gcc to have looser rules?
- How to make it compile in Linuxmint 17 or Ubuntu?

Summary:

- Concurrency Kit 0.4.4
- Linuxmint 17 (guess we¡¯ll have same error in Ubuntu)
- gcc 4.8.2
- GNU Make 3.81

Note the errors appear when building the application code, not when building the CK lib.

```
/usr/local/include/gcc/x86_64/ck_pr.h: In function ¡®void ck_pr_load_ptr_2(void*, void*)¡¯:
/usr/local/include/gcc/x86_64/ck_pr.h:169:22: error: invalid conversion from ¡®void*¡¯ to ¡®uint64_t* {aka long unsigned int*}¡¯ [-fpermissive]
  ck_pr_load_64_2(t, v);
                      ^
/usr/local/include/gcc/x86_64/ck_pr.h:153:1: error:   initializing argument 1 of ¡®void ck_pr_load_64_2(uint64_t*, uint64_t*)¡¯ [-fpermissive]
 ck_pr_load_64_2(uint64_t target[2], uint64_t v[2])
 ^
¡­... (lots more)
```

Compile options looks like this (note I use exactly same makefile in both hosts):

```
CXX    := g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Wcast-align -g -Wno-format
```

g++ version info in RHEL 7 (work)

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20140120/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20140120/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC)
```

g++ version info in Linuxmint 17 (NOT work)

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

Errors can be reproduced by having a new project and include some ck headers, since they come from library headers, e.g.

```
#include <ck_cc.h>
#include <ck_pr.h>
#include <ck_ring.h>
```

Comment: I know -fpermissive may allow it. But it is a bad idea to use it right?

Comment: It's passing a `void *` to a function expecting `uint64_t *`s. That's never valid C++ (though it is legal C). You should probably edit that header and add casts. As to why you didn't get it on other systems, probably some sort of conditional include is at work, so that the problematic header file wasn't included on those systems.

Comment: @T.C., thx but those code is definitely working in Redhat, as they are used to manage concurrency in the project. If it's illegal C++, I'd be shocked that it's allowed in RHEL. And it's been working just fine.

Comment: You can try it in Centos.

Comment: Like I said, a more plausible explanation is that the offending code may simply not be included when you compile in RHEL for whatever reason. Try using `g++ -E` on RHEL and check if it has `ck_pr_load_64_2`.